# Replace external jar dependency with local intellij project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar, dependency-management

So I have an intellij IDEA project (project A) which includes a bunch of external jar libraries. I am currently working on one of those external jar libraries (project B) and I want to replace it with the local project (project B) on my computer.

So, in short:
I have Project A which depends on jar B
I want to replace jar B with my local project (project B)

That way, when I run project A, it uses Project B local rather than Jar B external. Anyone know any good easy ways of doing this?

Comment: if you go to project structure tab, go to libraries, find your library, find it path, like "/Users/bla/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/openhtmltopdf/openhtmltopdf-core/1.0.0/openhtmltopdf-core-1.0.0.jar", you can generate and replace with your new jar in there, I think :)

Comment: Please check this discussion: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005958400-Resolve-dependencies-in-project-with-Gradle-Modules-?page=1#community_comment_360000823520

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin What do you mean "find it path"? After locating the library in the project structure, do you remove/delete it and then click "New Project Library" and then locate your local library?

Comment: I mean physically find the path and replace with a new jar, like copy and replace. actually @y.bedrov suggested right thing, [File]->[New]->[Module from existing sources]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using Composite Builds

Your use case is exactly what composite builds in Gradle are made for. [The docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_build_intro) even mention your precise use case:

> Composite builds allow you to […] combine builds that are usually developed independently, for instance when trying out a bug fix in a library that your application uses

A composite build allows you to temporarily and easily replace an external dependency library with a locally available build project of that library. (It would even work with multiple different dependencies.)

### Complete Example

Here’s how you’d set this up for your two projects (leaving out [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) files and Java source code for conciseness):

```
├── projectA
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
└── projectB
    ├── build.gradle
    └── settings.gradle
```

Note that the two project directories don’t actually have to be siblings. I’ve only done that here to keep it simple. In my minimal sample build, the two `settings.gradle` files can be empty. The two build scripts look as follows.

#### `projectA/build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:projectB:1.2.+'
}

repositories {
    // where you get the projectB dependency from normally
}
```

#### `projectB/build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.2.3'
```

#### Running the Sample

##### On the Command Line

Under `projectA/`, simply run `./gradlew --include-build ../projectB build` (or any other Gradle task(s) you’re interested in). Make sure to use the right path to the directory of projectB. The `--include-build` option automatically creates the composite build on-the-fly.

##### In IntelliJ IDEA

You can also create a composite build in IntelliJ. To do that:

1. Import projectA as usual (via its `build.gradle` file to make sure that IntelliJ automatically uses the Gradle configuration).
2. In the Gradle tool window, you click the <kbd>+</kbd> button (“Link Gradle Project”) and select the `build.gradle` file of projectB.
3. Right click projectA in the Gradle tool window and select “Composite Build Configuration”. In the opening dialog, select projectB and click “OK”.
4. In the Gradle tool window, click the  button (“Reload All Gradle Projects”).

That’s it. You should now be able to use projectA with its locally available dependency projectB.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open module A in IntelliJ IDEA;
2. Go to File-> Project Structure -> Modules -> module A -> Dependencies (Tab) -> find and delete B.jar (there is "-" button for that);
3. Next click "+" button and add folder which contains compiled classes of your local module B.

Comment: It's B.jar is a library. So it's under the Libraries tab.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the tag "gradle", I'm assuming you are using it for both projects. Run "gradle publishToMavenLocal" in project B and then refresh the dependencies of project A.

Just make sure you remember you did this and delete project B from your local repository when you are done with it.

Comment: I tried this and it still uses the original B.jar gradle dependency. Do I need to somehow reload maven?

Comment: You need to refresh the dependencies. In project A, go to the Gradle tab. Your project should be the root of the tree. Right click on it and select "Refresh Gradle Dependencies". If you then look at External Libraries under the project tab, you should see that it is referencing B's library in your local .m2 directory instead of .gradle\caches.

Comment: You need to add mavenLocal() to your repositories in project A

Comment: Yes, thanks. That's right.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with gradle:

In Project `A` build.gradle add `mavenLocal()` to the repositories.

```
...
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url ... }
}
...
```

In Project `B` you need the `maven-publish` plugin, and the related task.

```
plugins {
  id 'maven-publish'
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/main/java'
    }
  }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.main.allJava
  classifier = 'sources'
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifactId = rootProject.name //or some string eg.: 'projectb'
      groupId = project.group //or some string eg.: 'com.example'
      version = project.version //or some string eg.: '1.0.3.9'
      from components.java
      artifact sourcesJar
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can run the `publishToMavenLocal` task from your terminal, or from `Gradle View` in IntelliJ. (It is on the right side by default, gradle tab, expand your project and bellow publishing you can find the task.)

Comment: Do you mean `publishToMavenLocal`?

Comment: So I tried this and when I go back to project A, it looks like it still uses the original B.jar gradle dependency. I tried refreshing dependencies and I still get this. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.
The maven local must be the first on your repositories list, and it is recommended to change the version every time you run publish, because of gradle cache (or something else).